# pdo_pgsql could not find driver symfony2 + php problems

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I hope you're all good because i'm not, I have some trouble understand how Symfony 2 does work and I too have a extension problem (Could not find driver).

Firstly, php --ini tells me I have to edit my /etc/php.ini file BUT in my SF2 setting, i'm using Php 7.0.0 from MAMP, using /Applications/MAMP/.../php.ini and /Application/MAMP/../bin/php. So I should be using php 7.0.0 from MAMP shouldn't I ?

My web/config.php tells me "Set "xdebug.max_nesting_level" to e.g. "250" in php.ini* to stop Xdebug's infinite recursion protection erroneously throwing a fatal error in your project."

But i don't have any "xdebug.max" in my /etc/php.ini neither in my /Application/Mamp/../php.ini (I still don't know which one is used ... The one from my MAC or from Mamp ? Meh i'm so lost !)

That's my first problem, knowing which php.ini is used and why it appears to be the one in /etc.

Secondly, i've a "Could not find driver" error when i'm trying to generate bundle with php app/console doctrine:database:create

I searched on stackoverflow but all I found is that i had to check my phpinfo(); which says me that pdo_pgsql is enabled, then I went in /etc/php.ini and MAMP/php.ini to find the ";extension : pdo_pgsql" to uncomment but they already were ... So what's wrong ?

I'm trying to use postgreSQL database with SF2 and edited my config.yml and parameters.yml correctly I think. Here is my config.yml :

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_pgsql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
```

Well if anyone could help it'd be really cool, i don't understand why i have so much trouble understanding SF2. 
I absolutly need to know how to use php from MAMP.

Comment: MAMP is using localhost:8888 and symfony2 localhost:8000 So I guess i can't pretend using MAMP's php if they run on a different port ... I'll try this way

Comment: And the result of your attempts?